# Yomu and Heroku

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I just installed the 'yomu' gem (https://github.com/Erol/yomu) in my application and deployed to heroku.  On my local machine (Mac OS) it runs fine.  I noticed in the documentation it states that JRE is required for it to work.

When I run the application on Heroku I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/yomu-0.1.1/jar/tika-app-1.1.jar -t):
```

I'm assuming that yomu can't find the java compiler on Heroku.  Am I reading this right?  If I am, is there an add-on that I'm not considering?

By the way, the reason I'm using yomu is because it can extract text from doc and docx files.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Cedar stack?  If so I think Java should be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a java compiler - a java runtime (a JRE, like the documentation said). Installing a JRE as an addon is not (yet?) supported on Heroku.

Comment: thanks edovino...i chose to try out some other gems.  solution's not as pretty as yomu, but here's hoping that it'll be possible in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on the Cedar stack then a JDK is available to you at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk

I'm not sure how Yomu finds your Java install, but it's probably looking in JAVA_HOME. If so then setting JAVA_HOME on Heroku should make it work:

heroku config:add JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk

Answer (score 0):

In the new Heroku-16 stack, you can [add jvm as a buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-16-stack#testing-heroku-16-via-review-apps-apps-that-use-java-but-not-the-java-buildpack) and you don't need to configure paths or anything else. Just make sure to have it set as your first buildpack. I tried it with Yomu/Henkei and it worked for me.